# How to rename key and change value in json array

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, date

I have a json which is:

```
abc = """
    {"entities":[
        {"entity":"sys-date",
         "location": [38,56],
         "value":"2007-01-01"}
    ]}
"""
```

I need the entity name *sys-date* to be replaced by name *Year* and value should be updated as 2007 (extract year part from date).

The existing name *sys-date* and value *2007-01-01* should be deleted.

How do I go about doing it in python 2x. Please help.

Comment: You get json from string or file?

Comment: I recommend to add more relative tags before your post be downvoted. Tags like: json, regex, time are more related to your needs

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam exactly! And if he needs explicitly Python 2.x solution it must not be tagged with python-3.x

Comment: @cezar I couldn't agree more. Cool edition by the way ...

Comment: points noted Masoud and Cezar. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to load or dump json string to simple dict object in python and edit it as you want.

For editing datetime I use `datetime.strptime` to convert date string to datetime object.

You can read more about `strptime` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
import json
from datetime import datetime


json_string = '''
    {entities":[
        {"entity":"A","location":[12,19],"value":"B",‌​"confidence":1},
        {"en‌​tity":"C","location"‌​:[23,28],"value":"D"‌​,"confidence":1},
        {"e‌​ntity":"E","location‌​":[29,34],"value":"F‌​","confidence":1},
        {"‌​entity":"sys-date","‌​location":[38,56],"v‌​alue":"2007-01-01"}
        '''

json_dict = json.loads(json_string)

for item in json_dict['entities']:
    if item['entity'] == 'sys-date':
        item['entity'] = 'Year'
        date = datetime.strptime(item['value'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        item['value'] = date.year

json_string = json.dumps(json_dict)
```

Comment: This is brilliant Vlad. Thank you very much. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Nice! Although the value for the year could be simpler taken from the string: `json_dict['entities'][0]['value'][:4]`.

Comment: Yes, we can do this by splice, but i always do convert from string to datetime using `strptime` because in some case this is more efficient and simpler

Comment: is there a way i could do find replace like find where "sys-date" is in Json and replace it with Year and the same for find where "2007-01-01" is and extract year from it? Like is there a way apart from using dict position?

Comment: There could be strings where the position of the "sys-date" is not same. How do i create a generic function to scan through json object (irrespective of position) for finding "sys-date" and replace it with Year and extract year from corresponding date. Please advise.

Comment: aaa = """{entities":[{"entity":"A","location":[12,19],"value":"B","confidence":1},{"entity":"C","location":[23,28],"value":"D","confidence":1},{"entity":"E","location":[29,34],"value":"F","confidence":1},{"entity":"sys-date","location":[38,56],"value":"2007-01-01"}"""

Comment: bbb = """{entities":[{"entity":"A","location":[12,19],"value":"B","confidence":1},{"entity":"sys-date","location":[38,56],"value":"2007-01-01"},{"entity":"C","location":[23,28],"value":"D","confidence":1},{"entity":"E","location":[29,34],"value":"F","confidence":1}"""

Comment: Thank you so much Vlad. I am grateful. The updated code works perfectly.